# XmlSerializable Displaying self closing empty tag for nullable types having null value

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

In xml serialization I want to display self closing empty tag if a nullable type has null value. Below is my code for serialization.

```
 var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create),
            Encoding.UTF8);
            XmlSerializer ser =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            ser.Serialize(sw, leadsOnlineUpload, ns);
            sw.Close();
```

Comment: It serializes the property as a self-closing tag with an attribute `xsi:nil="true"` which shows the value is null.

Comment: but I also dont want to display xsi:nil="true" .